# Order of permutation

Tags: group-theory

What does order of permutation means???

and how to prove that the order of permutation of a finite set written in disjoint cycle form is the least common multiple of the lengths of the cycles

Comment: Exactly! That's why it makes sense to say about its order.

Comment: @user60079: You mean [symmetric group](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetric_group) instead of [symmetry group](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetry_group) (note the "not to be confused with" at the links).

Comment: @user60079: Does order of permutation is somehow related to symmetric groups?????

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The order of a permutation, as for any element of a group, is the smallest positive power it can be raised to that results in the identity. For a permutation $\sigma$ of a set $X$, if you focus on a single starting element $x\in X$, successive powers of $\sigma$ will move it through a sequence of elements until some power $m$ brings it back to $x$. However the power $\sigma^m$ may move other elements, and if one goes one taking higher powers $\sigma^k$, the image $\sigma^k(x)$ will again cycle through the same $m$ values one one has $\sigma^k(x)=x$ exactly when $k$ is a multiple of $m$, the order of the cycle of $x$ for $\sigma$. In order to have $\sigma^k$ fix every element, $k$ must simulataneously be a multiple of the orders of all cycles; the smallest value $k>0$ for which this happens is by definition the least common multiple of those orders.

Comment: suppose $\sigma = \begin{bmatrix}
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 \\
2 & 4 & 3 & 5 & 1 
\end{bmatrix}$ is one of the permutation $\sigma^{4}(1)$ is identity and similarly $\sigma^{4}(2)$,$\sigma^{1}(3)$,$\sigma^{4}(4)$,$\sigma^{4}(5)$.So to get order we have to take lcm(4,4,1,4,4)????

Comment: Yes, there are two cycles of elements here, $\{1,2,4,5\}$ and $\{3\}$. Elements in a single cycle always have their cycle of the same order and need not be reconsidered, so to get the order of $\sigma$ it suffices to take $\operatorname{lcm}(4,1)=4$. If there were a $3$-cycle and a $2$-cycle the order would have been $6$.

Answer (score 0):

The order of a permutation $\sigma$ of $E$ is the smallest integer $r$ such that $\sigma^r = \text{I}_E$ (identity on $E$).